# My app uses another website. Is it legal?

Tags: software

I would like to create an application/website which is automating some processes on another website A. So my application would basically use website A like a normal user would (there is no API available).

Is offering an application like this considered illegal? Since I would not have a permission from website A to do this.

The website is hosted in France.

Comment: What does the website's licence say?

Comment: There are very many websites that do just what you are talking about. Its really nothing new in the app / web world. Some websites don't care, some do. If the site does care, normally they will reach out to you and try to make some sort of arrangement with you like hitting their servers off hours or something. In a worst case, they will ban your IP address. You have two choices, reach out and ask for permission, or try and ask for forgiveness.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it's illegal; if you're using it through its normal web interface, the way users would, I'd think they'd be fighting an uphill battle to claim that your use is unreasonable. I think the bigger risk to you is that they would be fully justified in, and easily technically capable of, identifying and blocking connections by your app. Even if they don't specifically target you - and they could - nothing stops them from changing their site in ways that would break your app. What do you do then? I'd talk to the website just to avoid these problems, licensing aside.